# How can I override or even access a default method implementation from an interface within my subclass

Tags: c#, overriding

I understand that since C# 8 it has been possible to define 'default' implementations on interfaces. This code works for me:

```
IPerson s1 = new Student();
int age = s1.CalculateAgeOn(DateTime.Today);
Console.WriteLine(age);

public interface IPerson
{
    int CalculateAgeOn( DateTime date )
    {
        return 18; //Bogus implementation for illustration only
    }
}

public class Student : IPerson
{
}
```

However, I don't want to have to cast my `Student` to an `IPerson` (line 1 above) just in order to use `CalculateAgeOn` - that is defeating the point of polymorphism, it seems to me. If I change `IPerson` to `var` the `CalculateAgeOn` method is no longer visible.

I would be happy to override `CalculateAgeOn` the method in `Student` and delegate the implementation back up to the 'default' implementation, but I can't figure out how to do the override, let alone the delegation. (I already tried explicitly marking the default implementation on `IPerson` as virtual).

It seems to me that this must surely be possible: why else would this new feature be called a *default* implementation - that implies that other implementations are possible?

Answer (score 3):

You're running into the limitation of the default implementation of methods in interfaces: they're not base classes.

Thereby you're exactly pointing out the big issue a lot of people had when the [default interface methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods) were introduced in C#8

You must understand the history: in C# multiple inheritance was explicitly not allowed, because they didn't want to run into the issues that occurred with multiple inheritance in C++ (like the diamond problem, memory layout, etc.). However, since the beginning users have been complaining about this, as they were used to the feature. So, after all these years, Microsoft has decided they will allow a specific form of multiple inheritance in the form of the default interface methods. However, to prevent the issues that C++ had, they severely limited the functionality.

And that's that: is just not possible to "cast to base" with interfaces.
Instead you could think of using another solution to multiple inheritance: e.g. composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: I had read the documentation for default method on interface, but was just hoping that I had missed something!

Comment: @RichardPawson TBH what you are trying to do (casting to base to have the base behavior of a method instead of the overridden one) sounds very sketchy... if that's really required, there's something not quite right in the architecture and a refactor seems in place. Else you'll end up with difficult to maintain code because of unexpected behavior and such.

Answer (score 1):

As can be found in the [reference for default interface members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods):

> Note that a class does not inherit members from its interfaces; that is not changed by this feature:

So there is no inheritance involved.
You can write your own implementation for `CalculateAgeOn` in the `Student` class (or in another class derived from `IPerson`) but this will hide the default implementation, not override it.

Comment: So it really isn't a 'default' implementation, then. It's the 'one and only possible' implementation!

Comment: Pretty much so, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a method inside an interface when interfaces are designed as contracts, which should only contain method definitions.  See [Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interfac) more information.

In order for you to achieve your goal you could use an abstract class instead:

```
Student s1 = new Student();
int age = s1.CalculateAgeOn(DateTime.Today);
Console.WriteLine(age);

public abstract class Person
{
    public int CalculateAgeOn( DateTime date )
    {
        return 18; //Bogus implementation for illustration only
    }
}

public class Student : Person
{
}
```

Comment: My question was specifically about the 'default implementation' of a method on an interface, which Microsoft specifically introduced. I know lots of people disagree with that idea, but it exists and I was wanting to make use of it.  I am well aware of how abstract classes work, but that does not meet me requirement unfortunately. (Person/Student was a simplification. My hierarchy is much more complex, and the single abstract superclass is already being used for.)

Comment: @RichardPawson although not what you asked, it's the only way to overcome the limitation of you really want a "call to base" functionality. See my answer.